# Is there a way to fallback for missing glyphs with PIL?

Tags: python, fonts, python-imaging-library

When rendering text using PIL (ImageFont, ImageDraw, etc.) if the font is missing a glyph for a particular character, it just skips that character. I don't see any mechanism in the docs for specifying a fallback font. Is there a tried-and-true recipe for using a fallback font for missing glyphs in PIL?

Comment: Even worse, it draws a tofu character for me! =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to do this, but I did find a workaround. I used FontForge to fill in the missing glyphs in the main font, with backup glyphs from another font. As explained in this answer: https://superuser.com/questions/490922/merging-two-font-into-one

The only catch was that I'm running OS X 10.11.3, and the current stable release of FontForge just dies on that O/S. So I had to build FontForge from source. I did that following the "homebrew" instructions on this page:
https://github.com/fontforge/fontforge/blob/master/INSTALL-git.md

Comment: Obviously, if someone can tell me a way to do this without having to edit the fonts, I'll remove my check and give it to you!

Comment: Looking at [the source](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/), I see that `ImageFont` and `ImageDraw` – your example functions – both appear to use *bitmap* fonts, rather than "true" outline fonts (OpenType or TTF). Was that a conscious decision? (Prompted by your use of FontForge to adjust a font – did you indeed create a new *bitmap* font?)

Comment: No, I created a new TTF font using FontForge. The entire app uses only TTF fonts, so I'm guessing your reading of the source was incomplete.

Comment: .. Or possibly I was looking for the wrong thing. Sorry, I'll check again. (My idea is that somewhere in the code there might be an explicit check for missing glyphs. If I can locate that, it should be possible to make it go through a list of substitute candidate fonts as well.)

Comment: Is there a way PIL to return something that says that a particular character was not properly decoded and so a tofu was inserted in the resulting image?