# ImageFont detect missing glyph (Python Pillow)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

Here is a short [example](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageFont.html).

```
from PIL import ImageFont, ImageDraw

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

# use a bitmap font
font = ImageFont.load("arial.pil")

draw.text((10, 10), "hello", font=font)

# use a truetype font
font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 15)

draw.text((10, 25), "world", font=font)
```

> I want to know if the font is missing any glyphs from the rendered text.

When I try to render a glyph that is missing I get an empty square.

```
draw.text((10, 10), chr(1234), font=font)
```

- How to programmatically determine missing glyphs?
- How to list available glyphs in a **ttf** file?

The two questions are almost the same.

> I would prefer using Pillow to determine what I want.
>   Other modules from PyPI are welcome as well.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35436932/is-there-a-way-to-fallback-for-missing-glyphs-with-pil (But the solution there is to edit the font)

Comment: thanks, the best would be if I could list the available glyphs.

Comment: so is there any solution to know that a particular glyph is missing?

Comment: Unfortunately i found no solution. I use a heuristic approach to detect invalid glyphs of a given range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the '[fontTools](https://github.com/behdad/fonttools)' package, that includes a python class for reading and querying TrueType fonts. Something like this is possible

```
from fontTools.ttLib import TTFont
f = TTFont('/path/to/font/arial.ttf')
print(f.getGlyphOrder())      # a list of the glyphs in the order 
                              # they appear
print(f.getReversedGlyphMap() # mapping from glyph names to Id
id = f.getGlyphID('Euro')     # The internal code for the Euro character, 
                              # Raises attribute error if the character
                              # isn't present.
```

The mapping from characters to glyphs is often complex, and is defined in the cmap table of the font. It's a binary section, but can be inspected with

```
f.getTableData('cmap')
```

A font can have multiple cmap tables. The [freetype interface](https://github.com/rougier/freetype-py) can also read ttf files. It is possible to use freetype to attempt to render a character, and see the result: this would be slow.

```
import freetype as ft
face = ft.Face('arial.ttf')
face.set_size(25*32)
face.load_char(‽)
bitmap = face.glyph.bitmap.buffer
if bitmap == [255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 255, 255, 0, 255, 255, 0, 255, 255, 0, 255, 255, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255]:
     print("No interobang in the font")
```